# How to layer text over the image on 'Text and image' carousel item in the bootstrap extension of Typo3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

On my frontpage I have added the full-screen carousel content element of the bootstrap extension of Typo3. I would like to have both text and images on my slides so I added a 'Text and image' carousel item.

However, I would like the text to be layered on top of the image, instead of the image being placed below the text like shown in the image below.

[image: The 'Text and image' carousel item]

I would also like for the text to be centered and am unsure why it is not, since I am using the same header classes as for other carousel items where the text-center class is added automatically and the text is centered.

Comment: You need to override the Bootstrap css classes that are used and use things like "position:absolute;" and top, left, tight and/or bottom values. Also, assign the text element a higher z-index then the image (container).

Answer (score 0):

you may have to override the Carousel template (or some of its partial), in order to change classes and html element positions.
so when i am right and you are talking about the bootstrap_package extension the main template you like to override is:
web/typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentElements/Carousel.html